# Doctrine Random Native Query does not get all results

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need to choose 3 elements randomly from database, so I tried using this query:

```
    $em = $this->getEntityManager('MyBundle:Gift');

    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('MyBundle:Gift', 'g1');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('g1', 'id', 'id');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('g1', 'image', 'image');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('g1', 'special', 'special');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('g1', 'activationDate', 'activationDate');

    // Compute carthesian product to generate all possible combinations
    $result = $em->createNativeQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM gift g1, gift g2, gift g3 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3", $rsm
              )->getResult();
```

Running the query on MySQL always yields three result rows, but somehow Doctrine sometime gets just 2 results.

Maybe I'm not using the ResultSetMapper right, I do not know its API very well.

Comment: What is the generated SQL query?

Comment: It doesn't matter now. I had to implement the same query using DBAL and worked smoothly, though affected performance a little bit since I had to populate Gift entities by hand, generating multiple additional queries on the way.

Comment: But it was definitively an issue with the ResultSetMapping. I did some debugging and PDO was always retrieving 3 result rows.

Comment: It **actually** matters. You're saying that the result is wrong, but your result is coming from a generated SQL query, so we need to see the generated query to understand why your result is wrong and how to correct it. The DQL query is **also** welcome.

Comment: Ok, I'll provide some feedback later as a contribution to the community. But now it's impossible for me, no time to do it!